# Xamarin forms 3 color progress bar

Tags: xaml, progress-bar, xamarin.forms

In a Xamarin form, I want to show three color progress bar about three numbers to show on progress bar:

- Number of available questions
- Number of passed uestions
- Number of failed questions

I want it to look like this:

[Image showing progress bar with each categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztp2A.jpg)

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see three progress bars with same color on you image, please clarify your question

Comment: @Greensy these are three different progress bars. 
I need a progress bar with three different sections in it. 

like 
Total Questions
failed Questions 
passed Questions 

i want all this data on a single progress bar 
please tell me if its not clear yet

Answer (score 1):

I prefer use [Ncontrol](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NControl/) for all such custom controls. It is crossplatform, so you will not need any renderers

1) Install NControll to PCL and your platform projects

2) Subclass NControlView

3) Override Draw method

```
public class MyControl: NControlView
{
  private int _sectionOneValue = 0;
  private int _sectionTwoValue = 0;
  private int _sectionThreeValue = 0;

  public void SetSectionValues(int one, int two, int three){
      _sectionOneValue = one;
      _sectionTwoValue = two;
      _sectionThreeValue =three;
      Invalidate();
  }

  public override void Draw(NGraphics.ICanvas canvas, NGraphics.Rect rect)
  {
     var sum = _sectionOneValue+_sectionTwoValue+_sectionThreeValue
     if(sum == 0)
         return;

     var wOne = (rect.Width*_sectionOneValue)/sum;
     var wTwo = (rect.Width*_sectionTwoValue)/sum;
     var wThree = (rect.Width*_sectionThreeValue)/sum;


     canvas.FillRectangle (new Rect (0, 0, wOne, rect.Height ), NGraphics.Colors.Red);
     canvas.FillRectangle (new Rect (wOne, 0, wTwo, rect.Height ), NGraphics.Colors.Blue);
     canvas.FillRectangle (new Rect (wOne+wTwo, 0, wThree, rect.Height ), NGraphics.Colors.Green);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use my nugget package to implement this multi color progress bar.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/MultiColor.ProgressBar/

Documentation:
https://github.com/udayaugustin/ProgressBar/blob/master/README.md

You can just supply only one BarSegment to the list and create the view like your design.